# Prolog. Hallar nodo máximo en un árbol binario

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Buenas,

Quisiera saber cómo es posible hallar el mayor nodo en un árbol binario

Si tenemos un árbol de esta manera:

```
[[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
7,
[[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
6,
[[[],10,[]],
8,
[[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sólo podemos usar siguientes constructores y selectores del tipo abstracto de dato.

```
vacio([]).
raiz([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).
hd([_,_,HD],HD).
hazarbol(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD}).
```

¿Cómo puedo definir un predicado que halle el máximo nodo en el árbol de manera que  `mayordetodos(A4,M).`

```
M=11
```

Gracias